Blazor Web Assembly Project Connecting to CAS Service for Authorization
I'll preface this by saying that I'm not all that familiar with what the landscape of modern networks look like these days. I'll also preface this by saying this is a 2 factor auth problem that I need to solve using Blazor Web Assembly.
I built an application for connecting to a legacy tomcat database using Blazor Web Assembly. That piece of the project is complete save for a few fields which require some special treatment. One of those fields is the LDAP username of the person filling out the form. In order to grab this information, I need to find the user in the directory and get their LDAP from Active Directory.
Now, whenever a user accesses any resource on the network a 2 Factor is triggered to approve a users access to the resource they're trying to access. I need to implement this 2 Factor into my application. My contacts in the org told me there is a CAS resource available on the network and the corresponding library for accessing the CAS Resource is as follows:
https://github.com/apereo/dotnet-cas-client
The documentation for this library is pretty sparse on details and the ASP.NET project example is written for ASP.NET MVC which I know nothing about.

I'm using .NET 8. Will this library even work in .NET 8?
Does ASP.NET Core already have support for accessing a CAS server without having to use and understand an old 3rd party library?
What is required for an implementation of CAS in my application if this library does not work? Is it feasible for a single developer to communicate with a CAS endpoint?


Hi @Brady, 1.The dotnet-cas-client was primarily developed for older versions of ASP.NET MVC. Since .NET 8 introduces significant changes, this library may not work out-of-the-box.2.It seems ASP.NET Core doesn't have built-in support specifically for CAS. 3. Not sure which library you use and Yes, it is feasible for a single developer to implement CAS communication.
